# Pass string to class and save to eeprom

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm writing a class to save data to the EEPROM of an Arduino.
The class is called Memory.

The class contains different functions and variabeles.

```
char serverdefault[15] = "0032484716340";
int pricedefault = 30;

void Memory::FactoryReset()
{
  TotalSold = 0;
  TotalCash = 0;
  Sold = 0;
  Cash = 0;
  Items = 0;

  EEPROM_writeAnything(10, TotalSold);
  EEPROM_writeAnything(20, TotalCash);
  EEPROM_writeAnything(30, Sold);
  EEPROM_writeAnything(40, Cash);
  EEPROM_writeAnything(50, pricedefault);
  EEPROM_writeAnything(60, Items);
  EEPROM_writeAnything(70, serverdefault);

  ReadAll();
}
```

Annother function allows to change the default server number.

```
void Memory::ChangeServer(char *number_str)
{
  EEPROM_writeAnything(70, number_str);
  ReadAll();
}
```

This function doesn't work.
I call the function in the void setup().

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("started");
  Serial.println("factory reset");
  mem.FactoryReset();
  Serial.println("change server number");
  mem.ChangeServer("1234567890123");
}
```

The value saved in the EEPROM is replaced by "b32484716340" instead of "1234567890123". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is `EEPROM_writeAnything`? How is it declared? What does it do?

Comment: In `Memory::ChangeServer` you are writing the pointer itself to EEPROM (i.e. the address), rather than the string that the pointer points to.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is a libary im using to write to the EEPROM. http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/EEPROMWriteAnything

Comment: @PaulR How do i write the value tot the EEPROM instead of the pointer?

Comment: @JefGys: see answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Memory::ChangeServer` you are writing the pointer itself to EEPROM (i.e. the address), rather than the string that the pointer points to. One way to fix this would be:

```
void Memory::ChangeServer(char *number_str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(number_str); ++i)
    {
        EEPROM_writeAnything(70 + i, number_str[i]);
    }
    ReadAll();
}
```